# Why is my "valid" JS code not working?

Tags: javascript, toggle

I'm working on learning javascript, with a particular interest in toggling elements from being visible to not visible. I found a tutorial online, which works when I try to run it from my home server. But when I strip the code of everything fancy to just the bare basics, it stops working. I uploaded the code to jsFiddle, but the site says my code is perfectly valid. If it's valid, why isn't it working?

The original tutorial can be found [Here](https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Toggle-Function-Click-Drop-Down-Menus-Tutorial).

Can someone help me figure this out?

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0kjvwwxk/)

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="toggle('box');">Click here to toggle the box!</button>

    <div class="box">I am a Hidden Box!
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200;
    left: 200;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
    transition: height 0.3s linear 0s;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function toggle(x) {

    var panel = document.getElementByClassName(x);

    if (panel.style.display == "none") {
        panel.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        panel.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: `docoment.getElementByClassName()` returns an array of DOM nodes, even if there's only one, so you're operating `panel.style.display` when it should be `panel[0].style.display`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few errors.

First, you had the Javascript pane loading in `onLoad` but you're calling it globally, so your function wasn't accessible.

Second, you misspelled `getElementsByClassName`, you didn't have an `s`.

Third, `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array, so you have to access it as an array.

This works:

```
function toggle(x) {
    var panel = document.getElementsByClassName(x)[0];

    if (panel === undefined) {
        return;
    }

    if (panel.style.display != "block") {
        panel.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        panel.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0kjvwwxk/7/

Or (alternatively, if you don't have to support older versions of IE) you could check the *computed* style.

```
function toggle(x) {
    var panel = document.getElementsByClassName(x)[0];

    if (panel === undefined) {
        return;
    }

    if (getComputedStyle(panel).getPropertyValue("display") != 'block') {
        panel.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        panel.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0kjvwwxk/10

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but the `Element.style` property only detects styles assigned via the `style` attribute/property.

Comment: @DavidThomas - The OP is only trying to set it with the style attribute. I don't anticipate this to be a thorough examination of accessors and attribute states.

Comment: Hence my not down-voting your answer. I was only speculating as to the possible reason for the down-vote that was present on your answer at that point in response to the - since deleted - comment asking about it.

Comment: That happened literally two seconds after I posted it. I don't think there's much too, somebody may not have realized they did it.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that bit about getElementsByClassName being used as an array. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle wraps your code inside a closure for you.

Unfortunately that causes your function to be not accessible from the global scope.

You can fix this by attaching the function to the window object:

http://jsfiddle.net/0kjvwwxk/5/

`window.toggle = function(x) {` ...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed two problems in your code:

1. You're trying to get a node list, when you use the `getElementsByClassName` function, you're given a node list that you can use much like an array, in your case, you're not selecting a specific node from that list.
2. The function you're trying to fire from a attribute in the document isn't working (using event-attributes is also considered bad practice)

Here is what I did to make your code work:

```
function toggle(x) {

    var panel = document.getElementsByClassName(x)[0];

    if (panel.style.display == "none") {
        alert("plz");
        panel.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        panel.style.display = "none";
    }
}

document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function(){ 
  toggle("box");
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<button id="myButton">Click here to toggle the box!</button>
<div class="box" style="display:none;">I am a Hidden Box!</div>
```

(Notice I put the `display:none;` inline, because if the JavaScript, if it's not set inline, `.style.display` will just be unset, even if it's in a separate stylesheet)

http://jsfiddle.net/0kjvwwxk/6/

Answer (score 0):

It's `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClassName`, this method returns an array, if just have on element with this class name, you can use

```
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];
```

**`[0]`** is the first element in the array `panel` .

Example:

```js
function toggle() {

    var panel = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];

    if (panel.style.display == "none") {
        panel.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        panel.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.box {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200;
    left: 200;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
    transition: height 0.3s linear 0s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle();">Click here to toggle the box!</button>

    <div class="box">I am a Hidden Box!
    </div>
```